# Resize a fixed image inside an Image-sprite using css

Tags: css, image, user-interface

Created an image-sprite for all the images. In the css i am using background-image:"spriteimage" its position and height:150px and width:150px and then only full particular image inside a sprite is coming.(that image has got h&w as 150px only)
 I want to resize only that particular image to 35px 35px (small size)but when i use background-size: it readjusts the whole sprite image

Comment: I'm confused.. can you reword your question so we can understand it better

Comment: maybe you could use `transform: scale(0.23)` to change the size of your object?